# Capture system/window audio in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, audio, mediastream

I am currently experimenting with the getDisplayMedia browser api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia

I am successfully able to create a MediaStream video that captures an application, but it fails at capturing the audio (say for example I'm capturing a VLC video Running, there will be no audio track ever in the MediaStream).

I have tested that with both Chrome (83+) anf Firefox on Linux Mint and Windows, and it seems to fail everytime.

Also, when I'm trying to record audio only in Chrome (firefox not tested), it throws

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'getDisplayMedia' on 'MediaDevices': Audio only requests are not supported
```

I have read multiple dev threads, and it seems that it is not mandatory that the created MediaStream will contain audio, even though it is asked in the options.

So my questions are:

- is the audio option just complete decoration ? Because it seems
  pretty useless
- is there another way to capture audio ? for example with the Web Audio API ? I couldn't find any resource on that. Keep in mind that I want
  to capture **system or window** audio, not microphone.

Thanks for your answers

EDIT: Alright, I found that there's one possibility to capture audio: it has to be with Chrome, on Windows, and capture a screen (not an app). According to the doc, it should work with Edge too. I wonder if there are other means to capture the audio without some loopback device.

Comment: all browsers are intentionally designed to isolate the browser from the computer its running on ... this is a security and privacy consideration ...  the browser can open up and stream from the computer's camera + microphone yet is blocked from ability to tap into the computer's system audio or other system devices like files ... of course if the user downloads then installs an executable then anything is possible